# What's the difference between C++ Concepts and C++ Template Constraints?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

As the title says, there's something called [Concepts Lite](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf)
 (Template Constraints) and [Concept Design for the STL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf). Can anybody explain some fundamental differences between these?

Comment: One is healther if you plan to use it every day?

Answer (score 1):

The first introduces changes to the C++ language (core) to have facilities for expressing restrictions on templates. Providing sensible checks, good error messages to users and simple tools to template writers.

It will be developed as Technical Specification (TS) and expected by by mid 2014, about same time C++14. Compiler writers seem enthusiastic to ship it soon too.

The second is about library: current standard lib cna't use constraints that are not yet part of the standard for obvious reasons. But once that part is bose, the templates can and will be improved with more native expression of requirements.  I.e currently it's only written in the text that template argument must be default-constructible or assignable.  So if you use C++03 and `std::vector<std::auto_ptr<int> >` it's just UB. But with conceptized version such problems will be diagnosed at compile.